# Laravel - Many to Many on pivot table with Eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, many-to-many

I have three table which I wanna associate. **Shipment_methods**, **Ship_companies** and **Payment_methods**.

Relations:

Shipment_methods **<- pivot1 ->** Ship_companies

**pivot1** <- pivot2 -> Payment_methods

Well, what I wanna do is e.g. ShipmentMethod_A is attached to ShipCompany_B and for this record (from pivot1) I wanna attach record from Payment_method table through pivot2 table.

ShipmentMethod Model:

```
public function ship_companies()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(ShipCompany::class, 'shipment_methods_ship_companies', 'shipment_method_id', 'ship_company_id')->withPivot('price_kc', 'price_ha');
}
```

ShipCompany Model:

```
public function shipment_methods()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(ShipCompany::class, 'shipment_methods_ship_companies', 'ship_company_id', 'shipment_method_id');
}
```

What I need to do is I wanna retrieve all Payments for ShipCompany of specific ShipmentMethod like

```
ShipmentMethods->ship_companies->pivot->payments_methods
```

Thanx.

Comment: I'm quite sure you don't need a second pivot (hence, nor a second many-to-many relationship). You simply a need one-to-many relationship on the first pivot table, assuming that each pivot record only has one payment method. So you could just add that relation and all the other required model functionality to that pivot model using it as a custom one. Read more in the documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#defining-custom-intermediate-table-models

Comment: the payment methods will be smth like bank account, card, in cash etc. and them can be attached to any ship company, so ship company 1 can have card, cash but e.g. ship company 2 accept only cash... and with another SM can SC2 have only card etc.

Comment: Anyway, you can extend the functionality of the first pivot as a normal eloquent model, just register it as a custom one. Then you can attach all the relations you want to it and work out your logic as you please. Take a look at the docs I've sent you

Comment: have you tried what you wrote and it didn't work ?

Comment: yes, I did. Doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 5):

I think best way is for you to have a `Model` that extend `Pivoted` class for you *pivot1*. the *pivot1* should have **id** column to use in *pivot2*. so the code should be like this,

**ShipmentMethod Model:**

```
public function ship_companies()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(ShipCompany::class, 'shipment_methods_ship_companies', 'shipment_method_id', 'ship_company_id')->using('App\pivot1')->withPivot('id','price_kc', 'price_ha');
}
```

*note that I have put id in `withPrivot` and chain `using()` method*

your *pivot1* model should be like this,

**pivot1 Model:**

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Pivot;

class pivot1 extends Pivot
{

    public function Payment_methods()
    {
      return $this->belongsToMany(Payment_methods::class, 'pivot2_table_name', 'pivot1_id', 'payment_method_id');
    }
}
```

and at the end you can do like this to save to *pivot2*

```
ShipmentMethods->ship_companies->pivot->payments_methods()->sync([payment_method_ids])
```

as all pivot relationship return a collection of array note that you need to loop `ShipmentMethods->ship_companies` relationship to get to pivot relationship.

Hope this helps!

Comment: `$shipmentMethod[0]->shipCompanies[0]->pivot->paymentMethods` show empty Collection, but `$shipmentMethod[0]->shipCompanies[0]->pivot` show new created Pivot Model without relations. What am I doing wrong? I dunno how to associate paymentMethods with pivot in with clause so I am using `$shipmentMethod = ShipmentMethod::with(['shipCompanies'])->get();`

Comment: @MichaelMotúz, I'm having the same problem. Did you found a solution?